# Question facebook policy and app developers

Tags: facebook

In 2014, Facebook enacted rules that mandates developers to get friends' permission and another rule that app developers must get approval from facebook before requesting access to sensitive data. I am wondering what effect this has had on your experience as an app developer. Secondly, I am also wondering what effect the new rules have had on your experience as an app developer. By new rules, I am referring to the ones that Facebook released in March 2018, namely: the ban of those developers who do not consent to auditors, removing access to data after 3 months of no use, and the ability of users to revoke permission. Lastly, I am wondering to what extent you believe the following statement to be true, especially in the context of Facebook in recent times:
"There is no point to developing social network apps that can’t involve the user’s social network."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question

Comment: also, this is highly opinionated, which is off topic on stackoverflow too.